# Using Elasticsearch, in the following scenario, why the word segmentation results are the same, but the query results are different

Tags: elasticsearch

My index uses [word_delimiter_graph](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-word-delimiter-graph-tokenfilter.html) to do word segmentation for English, mainly to use special characters or camel-cased words into individual words, The tokenizer creation code is as follows

```js
{
    analysis: {
        analyzer: {
            html_custom_analyzer: {
                char_filter: ['html_strip'],
                tokenizer,
                filter: ['custom_word_delimiter_graph_filter', 'lowercase'],
            },
        },
        filter: {
            custom_word_delimiter_graph_filter: {
                type: 'word_delimiter_graph',
                catenate_all: true,
                preserve_original: true,
                stem_english_possessive: true,
            },
        },
    },
}
```

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcDV3.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynF12.png)

[iamge 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzI5K.png)

What I want is to match the camel case can match the complete one, and can also match the word segmentation, the complete score is higher, can this be done, how to change the configuration item

What I want is to match the camel case can match the complete one, and can also match the word segmentation, the complete score is higher, can this be done, how to change the configuration item